# Как получить температуру CPU, GPU и т.д. на golang?

Tags: golang, системное-программирование

Были уже похожие вопросы, но конкретно про windows и к тому же без ответов или с неработающими ответами.

Я пробовал такой код:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ssimunic/gosensors"
)

func main() {
    sensors, err := gosensors.NewFromSystem()
    // sensors, err := gosensors.NewFromFile("/path/to/log.txt")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Sensors implements Stringer interface,
    // so code below will print out JSON
    fmt.Println(sensors)

    // Also valid
    // fmt.Println("JSON:", sensors.JSON())

    // Iterate over chips
    for chip := range sensors.Chips {
        // Iterate over entries
        for key, value := range sensors.Chips[chip] {
            // If CPU or GPU, print out
            if key == "CPU" || key == "GPU" {
                fmt.Println(key, value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но пакету `gosensors` нужен `lm-sensors` который очевидно на windows не поставить, а мне нужна кросс-платформенная программа.

**Так как всё-таки получить температуру CPU и GPU на GoLang?**